# How to put the scrolling line chart when bulk of data?

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

Currently I'm evaluating Kendo ui control for task of rendering huge data collections  as line charts.
I need the following chart behavior:
- scrolling should work always on all data (no input data cut is possible though)
- Everything should work relatively fast (especially on scrolling)

I know how to achieve part of requirements using ChartDataSource, but I can't understand if it's possible to implement such dynamic adaptive data sampling on proper scrolling support.
I am exactly want chart this type :-http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ChartView/SmoothScrolling

Could you please advise if it's possible? Is this feature planned?

Thanks.